# How to stretch an icon to fill parent?

Tags: flutter

I need an icon that will dynamically stretch to fill the parent container.

I don't think this is possible directly on the Icon (since it only has a **size** property), but is there another solution I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 35):

I believe you can use `FittedBox` with `Expanded`:

```
new Expanded(
    child: new FittedBox(
      fit: BoxFit.fill,
      child: new Icon(Icons.home),
    ),
),
```

Please note the in the docs that `Expanded` has to be wrapped in a `Column`, `Row` or `Flex` widget.

References:

- [`Expanded`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html)
- [`FittedBox`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/FittedBox-class.html)
- [`BoxFit`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/painting/BoxFit-class.html)
- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/flutter-dev/lsgdU1yl7xc/0pYS2qrzBQAJ

Comment: UPDATE- only wrap your icon with FittedBox like in the answer. You don't have to use expanded anymore.

Comment: @ÇağrıKırt I think that depends on how you're using the FittedBox. I have mine in a Row, in a Column. Without Expanded wrapping the FittedBox, FittedBox does nothing.

Answer (score 3):

To expand the size of icon and fill his parent widget used expand it with SizedBox and fill the icon with FittedBox widget

```
SizedBox.expand(
   child: FittedBox(
      fit: BoxFit.fill,
        child: Icon(Icons.volume_off),
   ),
),
```