# Make row fit within Container

Tags: flutter

I have a row in a container. The row consists of a Column of text and a png going from left to right. The png needs to fit in the container snugly not too short and not over flowing. This is what I currently have: [image].

I can't get the png to fit snugly in the container

Comment: Can you publish the code you're using ?? I suspect your image to be too big, you can use the `fit` argument to make your image fit in.

Comment: Did you try any of these solutions? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45745448/how-do-i-stretch-an-image-to-fit-the-whole-background-100-height-x-100-width https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46008569/can-flutterlogo-be-made-to-stretch-to-fill https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45299847/how-to-stretch-an-icon-to-fill-parent 
This question seems like a duplicate

Comment: apologies for the late response. I used stacks instead of putting the png and column of text in a row. The png fitted 'snugly' with that approach.